# Can you create a Case via ExactTarget integration?

Tags: marketing-cloud, case, ampscript, case-object

We're able to create leads, contacts and tasks without any problems from ExactTarget Landing Pages using ampscript and the Salesforce integration. I've tried creating a Case using simple code like the below:

```
SET @CaseID = CreateSalesforceObject("case", 11,
    "OwnerID", "005C0000004AXXX",
    "Still_in_1st_10_Weeks__c", "No",
    "ContactID", "003C000001YuXXX",
    "Opportunity__C", "006C000000nrXXX",
    "Sales_Rep_on_Account__c", "005C0000004AXXX",
    "Product_Category__c", "BrandName",
    "Number_of_Cards__c", "10",
    "Status", "New",
    "Type", "Problem",
    "Origin", "Sales",
    "Reason", "Other"
    )
```

But, this code only get's me this error:

```
An unexpected error has occurred!
Error Message:  Call to create the salesforceobject case failed! Error status code: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY Error message: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Description:    An unexpected error occurred during the execution of the page.

line 0, column 0
Exception Info:

Call to create the salesforceobject case failed! Error status code: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY
Error message: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

:  
Source:
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on whether this is possible or not and what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance, Kevin

Comment: Do you know if your account has been set up for Salesforce, and you have installed the AppExchange ExactTarget application in your SFDC account?

Comment: Looks to be a permission issue, the case is being related to Users (OwnerId and Sales_Rep_on_Account__c), Contacts (ContactID), and Oppurtunities (Opportunity__C).  The tracking user defined within Salesforce must not have access to one of these object types which is why it is throwing an error, not sure which one though.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews - Hey Kelly, yes, this account has the AppEchange ExactTarget application installed. We're good sending emails to reports and campaigns and have used ampscript on landing pages to pull lead/contact info, create leads, tasks and so on.

Comment: @Mac, thanks Mac, we were wondering if it was just an issue with permissions. I'll try and get with the Salesforce Admin for the tracking user and see if there's something to change that fixes it. If so, I'll post back here. Thanks again.